# How to redirect to logout when token expired in angular?

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

I have a angular 13 application. There I use JWT token for authentication purposes. Everything works fine. but the token expiration time I have given to the JWT token is 1 hour. I want to log the user out from the front end application once the token expired on the server-side.

I did this but it seems there is a problem and it didn't work for me:

```
export class authInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.userService.isAuthentificated()) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.userService.getToken()}`
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(event => {
      }, error => {
        this.onSubscribeError(error);
      })
    );
  }

  private onSubscribeError(error: any): void {
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
      this.userService.logout();
    }
  }
}
```

can anyone tell me what I did wrong and help me correct it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect to logout when token expired in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266733/how-to-redirect-to-logout-when-token-expired-in-angular-4)

Comment: I'll try it and see

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by E. Maggini is fine, technically, but the accepted answer for it, at least, is only relevant for letting the server decide if it's expired or not.

If you're not making calls to the server and getting your 401, your UI stays logged in until you do.

You need a mix of the two; one added to your interceptor to check for your 401 and log you out (to be sure) and the app itself checking the token.

Simplest is to just have an interval on the go checking for your token's expiry.

Assuming you have some kind of singleton `AuthService` with basic login/logout handling...

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private jwt: string;
    private expiryTimer: any;

    public login(jwt: string): void {
        this.jwt = jwt;
        this.expiryTimer = setInterval(() => { this.checkExpiry(); }, 60000);
        this.router.navigate(['...']);
    }

    public logout(): void {
        this.jwt = undefined;
        if (this.expiryTimer) clearInterval(this.expiryTimer);
        this.router.navigate(['...']);
    }

    private checkExpiry(): void {
        if (this.jwtService.hasExpired(this.jwt)) this.logout();
    }
}
```

Assuming you have some jwt service or method or whatnot to check the expiry...

It'll look more complicated than that as, presumably, you'd actually be storing the token somewhere (local storage?) so that page refreshes are handled, etc. etc.

But the basics are there - don't overthink it, it's as simple as just checking the token every x (1m good enough?) and if it's expired, logout...

Your modified interceptor will use the same thing; get a 401? `this.authService.logout();`. Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create HttpInterceptor class like yours and follow the steps as mentioned
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  // Inject your AuthService
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    
    // Find your login response from authService
    const loginResponse = this.authService.getLoginResponse()

    // Check loginResponse?.token has any token
    if (loginResponse?.token) {
        
      // Check expire time coming from server response
      let tokenExpirationDate: any = new Date(loginResponse?.expiresAt);

      if ((tokenExpirationDate > new Date())) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${loginResponse.token}`
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        // Call logout
        this.authService.logout();
      }
    }
    else {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: ""
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```